# how to upload any file to google drive using Ubuntu file manager

Tags: filemanager, upload, google-drive

I am not getting the way to upload any file to Google drive as the drive is just like a folder in Ubuntu and copy paste of any file to drive does not uploads it and also i haven't seen any option to upload any file to Google drive in the file menu . 
So in short is there any way to upload files to Google drive using Ubuntu file manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use grive to sync the files automaticly.
You can find a tutorial how to set it up here:
http://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/ubuntu-google-drive-client-grive-and-grive-tools

I don't think there is a way to do it through nautilus.

Comment: the thing is that i am using the gnome environment so can you suggest me to do the same thing with gnome versions

Comment: Grive supports Gnome, so it should work perfectly fine :)

Comment: i have followed the same steps as displayed but i did'nt shows any effect

Comment: Did you get an error anywhere?

Comment: sorry i got my problem corrected i just restarted my pc and everything is right now here

Comment: Good to hear :)